# Help with calculating the variance of a random variable

Tags: random-variables, variance

I have this question from a previous exam:

At any given time, a particle can jump to the left, to the right, or stay in its position on a horizontal axis, each possibility with equal probability. Let $S_n$ be the position of the particle after $n$ steps. *Note that the initial position of the particle is* $0$.

I'm first asked to write $S_n$ as a sum of $n$ independent random variables that represent the
displacements at different steps.

I wrote $S_n$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ where $X_i = \left\{ \begin{aligned} -1 \\ 0 \\ +1 \end{aligned} \right.$

Is my $S_n$ correct? And the question that follows asks us to determine $Var(S_{2500})$, so how do we do that?

Comment: I think you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: @MattiP. Is my $S_n$ correct? Because with it I got the variance to be zero.

Comment: **Hint:** The variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the individual variances.

Comment: First you may want to compute the variance of $X_1.$ It is not zero.

Comment: @DavidK $Var(S_1) = E(S_1^2) - E(S_1)^2$. $E(S_1) = \sum_{x} {x\cdot P(X=x)} = -\frac13 + \frac13 = 0$. $E(S_1^2) = \sum_{x} {x^2\cdot P(X=x)} = \frac13 + \frac13 = \frac23$. Finally, $Var(S_1) = \frac23 - 0 = \frac23$. Am I getting this right?

Comment: And $Var(S_{2500}) = 2500 \cdot Var(S_1) = \frac{5000}{3}$. Am I right?

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: Okay thank you @DavidK, you've been most helpful.